# Embed Vimeo Video in full width

Tags: html, css, video, vimeo

I embed a vimeo video on my website like this:

```
<div class="fys-fp-content-wrapper">
<div id="fys-fp-video">
</div>
</div>

#fys-fp-video {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 600px;
}
#fys-fp-video iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}
```

The Vimeo iFrame is loaded into #fys-fp-video.

However the Video in its original is only 640px width. I want to always display the video in a width of 100%, regardless whether something of the video is but of because of the 600px height, but it is important that it is shown full width.

Does somebody has a hint how I can achieve that?
thanks!

Comment: can you edit the embed tag into the post?

Answer (score 5):

If you use bootstrap, it's easy :

```
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

Source Bootstrap 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/

Update Bootstrap 5:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/ratio/#example

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe lass="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/54596361" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `vw` (viewport width). `width:100%` means 100% width of the parent. `width:100vw` means 100% of the screen. I suggest you do like this:

```
#fys-fp-video {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 600px;
}
#fys-fp-video iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: but then this happens: http://d.pr/i/7egC I still have a black empty area around the video...

Comment: Try adding `width:100vw` to `#fys-fp-video`